# Django Unique Constraint Specific Field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, ag-grid-angular

I have a A model which uses model B and C as ForeignKeys. In A model, I want to create a constraint that lets saving only if model B and 'xyz' field in C model are unique.
When I do it as follows, it did not work. How can I achieve this?

```
class A(models.Model)::
   B = models.ForeignKey("B", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   C = models.ForeignKey("C", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   
   class Meta:
     unique_together = [
         ('B' , 'C.xyz')
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can do that with `unique_together`.
According to django version, you can use [`UniqueConstraint`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint) instead so:

```py
class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['B', 'C__xyz'], name='...')
    ]
```